# sendmail R command regular expression adding exclusions to Kcheckaddress regex -a@MATCH

Tags: regex, sendmail, spam-prevention

I'm trying to get some exclusions into our sendmail regex for the [R command](https://books.google.com/books?id=upCgAjrpJfgC&pg=PT250&lpg=PT250&dq=K%20command%20regex%20%20sendmail%20R$%20&source=bl&ots=7QD825dTpR&sig=i5noQ1uZ07PDmxFoqa2wilhJChU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwkN72utHQAhWHhlQKHaxJD5oQ6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=K%20command%20regex%20%20sendmail%20R%24%20&f=false). The following configuration & regex works:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
#
Kcheckaddress regex -a@MATCH
    [a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+<@[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+?\.+[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+?\.(us|info|to|br|bid|cn|ru)
LOCAL_RULESETS
SLocal_check_mail
# check address against various regex checks
R$*                             $: $>Parse0 $>3 $1
R$+                             $: $(checkaddress $1 $)
R@MATCH                         $#error $: "553 Your Domain is Blocked for Unsolicited Mail"
```

So we are blocking anything@subdomain.domain.us but not anything@domain.us. I'd like to add exclusions for cities and schools so to allow  user@ci.somedomain.us and user@subdomain.[state].us. (note that [state] means 1 of the 50 states including DC).

This regex is not working (using CA for California as a test):

```
(?!.*\@ci\..+?\.us$)(?!.*\@*\..+?\.ca.us$)([a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+?\.+[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+?\.(us)$)
```

I get this error:

```
sendmail -bt
/etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 199: pattern-compile-error: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

What surprises me, in order to get the regex that does work that it requires the leading spaces and I'm not sure what the function of the `+<@` part of the regex does? What is the less than (<) doing here? Does it need to be added to the bigger regex?

edit: I'm pretty sure that [sendmail's R & K](http://www.xiitec.com/blog/2009/02/25/using-regular-expressions-in-sendmail/) commands do not support negative look-aheads. So if anyone can help re-write the regex in a sed-friendly format I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria is not clear, you say block all subdomains but then allow them too?
Unless you are using the user name specifically, don't match it.

Block 
 sub.domain.us 
Allow
 sub.sub.domain.us
or domain.us

```
Ksubsubdomains regex -a@MATCH @([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+\.){2}us

Ssubsub
R$+             $: $(subsubdomains $1 $)
R@MATCH         $#error $: "553 No Thank You."



# sendmail -bt                     
Enter <ruleset> <address>
 > subsub a@sub.sub.us
 subsub             input: a @ sub . sub . us
 subsub           returns: $# error $: "553 No Thank You."
> subsub a@sub.sub.sub.us
subsub             input: a @ sub . sub . sub . us
subsub           returns: a @ sub . sub . sub . us


since states have 2 letter abbreviations, block sub domains of 3 or more characters 

Ksubstates regex -a@MATCH @[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+\.([a-zA-Z_0-9]){3,}+\.us
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different approach as [suggested on the SpamAssassin mailing](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spamassassin-users/201706.mbox/browser) list. I used sendmail's access.db. Since the [locality namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.us#Locality_namespace) I want to white list are all fourth-level domain registrations of the form "`<organization-name>.<locality>.<state>.us`" I simply created 50 entries for all the states like below, starting with rejecting anything.us:

```
From:us     REJECT
From:ma.us  OK
From:mi.us  OK
```

I haven't seen ANY false negatives, i.e., missed spam, since enabling this for a few days now.